# How to bulk copy sql (export) tables to a csv or tsv files in .Net?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

Are there any .Net libraries that provide a way of exporting sql database data to plain text files (i.e. csv\tsv)? SqlBulkCopy only applies to the import part of the solution and I prefer not to be calling any Process.Start calls to open up command prompts to call bcp.exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up using bcp Process calls unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Check out [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) - it allows you to easily load or save data from CSV or other text file formats. Excellent code base, freeware, full C# source available - can't recommend it enough!

Answer (score 1):

As such there is no .net library which you can use for export data into txt/csv. You can use StreamWriter to write data in txt/csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet for what JK was saying:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();             
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "BCP.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"SELECT * FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.TABLENAME\" queryout \"FILENAME.txt\" -S \"SEVERNAMEHERE\" -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -c -k";
p.Start(); 
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would calling a stored procedure work for you?
I did a quick Google for using bulk copy in a procedure and found this article:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/